# Is it feasible to measure one-way speed of light this way?

Tags: speed-of-light

I know that this subject is pretty saturated even thought i waited a few days.Its a generalized theoretical expiremental set up to try and measure one way speed of light,i just want any input on this but beware it will require a few minutes of your spare time.

(**Last edit:The fundamental flaw is that the problem of simultaneously can not be avoided in any way**)

*Theoretical experiment for measuring one way speed of light*

From 1905 to this day we have not experimentally measured the one way speed of light between a source to the detector only the roundtrip from the source to the detector and back again. We just assume that the speed of light is the average speed and it’s the same at all directions equal to c. But I think it is important to point out that this is just a convention not an empirically verified fact. The aim of this paper is to provide a general methodology using a theoretical experiment that aims, if it gets implemented, to prove or disprove that the speed of light is equal at least in two directions along the horizontal axis. It’s not meant to provide specific technical details and it will require some modifications if it ever gets attempted.

We can start setting up our theoretical experiment now, which I call “The Weight Race Experiment/Method”. First of all we need some kind of containment or room to experiment. For simplicity’s sake we will go with the room. So now we take an optical fiber of certain length and cut it exactly in half. We use a laser that can shoot a vertical light beam in two angled and connected mirrors that split the beam and redirect them into the two out of the four non connected ends of the fibers we just cut respectively. Now we attach a rigid rod above the optic fiber and also make the system able to rotate (except the laser and the mirrors) around its center of gravity which would be near the center of our fiber. Also our system will be supported by the wall in a way that the two spheres are facing downwards. We now attach at the two edges of the fiber two special identical in every way clamps that each hold two also identical in every way spheres(also when light hits the special clamps they move to the open position at exactly the same time). Keep in mind that we still try to make everything be level. Last step is to remove as much air we can from the room and get it as close to a vacuum as possible.

Once the whole system is at rest and the two weights are balancing each other out we start by shooting two simultaneous light beams at each edge of the fiber optic. If the speed of light is the same in all directions then the whole system will remain at the same position and not rotate. If it’s not then the center of gravity will shift for a very small amount of time and it will make the (fiber/device/rod) system rotate and depending on how different the speed of light is in each direction the angle will increase in value relative to the original rest position of the whole system. That means that the difference between the different speeds of light and the angle created are analogous. Larger difference results in larger angle, which we can measure using an already built in sensor before the experiment even start.

Comment: What makes you believe this experimental setup is any different from the past attempts to measure a one way speed of light?  What aspect of it is fundamentally different from the previous attempts?

Comment: Why the vacuum? Light travelling through fiber optics is travelling through fiber optic medium no matter what medium or vacuum the fiber optics are in.

Comment: It does not need synchronized clocks to work.The variation does not even needs to measure anything in real time.Of course if no problems arise that i have not thought of,thats why i want inputs.

Comment: The vacuum is for the four or two objects used as weights respectively in this case the  spheres.I want to have free fall without air resistance so i know exactly that how long they will take to fall,so i can measure the delay.Also its usefull if you want repeatability.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when one is constructing a device that is considered impossible by nearly all physicists, there's a reason it doesn't work.

We'll start with before step 1:

> We take a special device that can shoot two light beams from two opposing holes located at each side of the machine simultaneously and we attach the two out of the four non connected ends of the fibers we just cut in the two holes accordingly.

How do you know the light leaves both holes simultaneously?  How is that calibrated?  You'll find that, to calibrate this properly, you either have to have measured the direction-specific speed of light, or you will have to assume that it is the same speed in all directions (in which case you measure the time it arrives at the center of the chamber).

Comment: Its not about leaving the holes at the same time more of starting at the same time from a single point. Of course i am not knowledgeable enough to know such a device so i assumed that there has to be way to produce two opossing light beams at the same time with some process.Well anyway thx  for your input.

Comment: There is such a way.  You just start by assuming light travels the same speed in all directions!  Then it is relatively straight forward.  However, if you aren't making this assumption, you find a chicken and the egg problem, because you're trying to measure something that can't be measured.

Comment: I assume that light travels the same speed in all directions at the start of the expirement to predict the results we are waiting to see and if they differ from reality.I suppose that you meant,if not correct me please.

Comment: So let us say that your system detects an imbalance.  How do you tell whether it is an imbalance in the inputs, or an inbalance in the speed of light inside your test chamber?  Or worse, if you detect no imbalance, how do you tell if that means the speed of light was the same in all directions, or if it just happened to cancel the effect of the inputs being out of sync?

Comment: Lets assume for a second that our method is indeed possible to wield results. We find out that we  have the problems you say above then shouldn't trying to make more precise and  repeating it many times solve them or minimize them?

Comment: Have you written out, in algebraic form, what you are trying to solve for?   I am expecting it will take the form of trying to find the unique values for a and b such that (x+a) + (y+c) = z, where x y and z are measurable.  You will, of course, never find unique values for this as there are an infinite number of possible values satisfying the equation.

Comment: @kostarak You just used the world "simultaneously" in your description.  This is the key to the problem.  This implies the synchronization of two events at different spatial locations. How are you going to do that?